# How to exclude a worker from the pool available to the beat scheduler?

Tags: django, heroku, celery

I have a Django app running on Heroku, with several production instances (different versions of the app, run with different env variables).

I am using Celery with Redis and CloudAMQP.

The contents of my Procfile:

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn {appname}.wsgi
worker: celery -A {appname} --concurrency=3 worker
beat: celery -A {appname} beat
```

The beat is only used in app A. Only app B is currently using a worker (those dynos are only used in those particular apps).

What I'm trying to do is start an app C. It needs a worker to run tasks invoked in the code, but  that worker cannot be used to run scheduled tasks - they should all be run from app A.

As I understand it, beat uses any free worker from the available pool. Is there a way to exclude a worker provided in app C from those used by beat?

---

**EDIT:**
I read up on some documentation, but I still cannot make this work.

There are several apps in my Django project that have tasks.py file with specified tasks in them. I divided the files so that in any single file there are tasks of only one type (run periodically or invoked from the code). In my celery.py file:

```
app.conf.task_routes = {
    'communication.tasks.*': {'queue': 'called_tasks'},
    'reservations.tasks.*': {'queue': 'cron_tasks'}
}
```

My Procfile now is:

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn {appname}.wsgi
worker: celery -A {appname} --concurrency=3 worker -Q cron_tasks,called_tasks
called_tasks_worker: celery -A {appname} --concurrency=3 worker -Q called_tasks
beat: celery -A {appname} beat
```

I have one beat dyno running in app A, one worker dyno running in app B and one called_tasks worker running in app C.
All those apps are using the same CloudAMOP and Redis (there is a single add-on of each with all those apps attached).

What I want to see is:

- tasks from cron_tasks queue run by worker,
- tasks from called_tasks queue invoked in app B to be run by worker,
- tasks from called_tasks queue invoked in app C to be run by called_tasks_worker.

But it's not happening with the above configuration. Tasks from cron_tasks are run only by worker, but there are some tasks from called_tasks invoked in app B that are run by called_tasks_worker.

How can I make it work?

Comment: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/routing.html

Comment: @iklinac thank you, I read it and tried to fix it, but i still can't make it work. I edited the post with my progress.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case and setting `app.conf.task_routes` didn't help either.

Here is what you should do instead:

```
from kombu import Queue

app.conf.task_queues = (
    Queue(
        "called_tasks",
        routing_key="communication.tasks.#",
    ),
    Queue(
        "cron_tasks",
        routing_key="reservations.tasks.#",
    ),
)
```